# i want to check for empty values in assocative array then create another array using its keys

Tags: php

I  have an associative array called $row from a user input form, i want to check if any of its values is empty, if any value is empty i want to create another associative array called $error[] and push those empty values into this associative arrays but i want to use the keys of the empty array as name of the error array so that i can know which fields were empty.

for example the row array is as follows $row = array ('name'=>'martin','tel'=>023, 'experience'=> 'high');

i want to create an error array as follows to check if name, tel,or experience are empty.

if  i find for example name and tel are empty, i want the error array to be as follows $error['name']= 'name cannot be empty'
$error['tel']='tel cannot be empty'

I have very many input values that i want to loop through.

here is the code i have tried but i get an error of undefined offset.

```
function is_empty($row){
    $errors= []; 
    $countRows = count($row); 
for($i=0; $i<=$countRows;$i++){
 if(empty(trim($row[$i]))){
    $i = (string)$i;
    $errors[$i] =  $i ."is empty";
 }
}
   return $errors;
}

$errors = is_empty($row);

      if(!empty($errors)){

          return $errors;
      }

print_r($errors);
```

i am not getting an associative array from this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this with simple [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/array_filter)? It'll take the elements of array where the value is empty and then a single foreach loop to print or make your error message. Hope this helps :)

```
<?php
$row = array ('name'=>'martin','tel'=>null, 'experience'=> 'high','password'=>'','occupation'=>'');
$missing_values = array_filter($row, function($value) { return $value == ''; });
$error = [];
print_r($missing_values);
foreach($missing_values as $k=>$v){
    $error[$k] = "$k can't be empty";
}

print_r($error);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
        [tel] => tel can't be empty
        [password] => password can't be empty
        [occupation] => occupation can't be empty
     )
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/akRoB

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the value in the key is empty and if the key is set.

```
function is_empty($row)
{
    $errors=array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($row[$key]) && $row[$key] == '') {
            $x[$key] = $key." is empty";
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.
 In any answer where you said to "try this" without explanation, you should update your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function fill_error(&$item,$key) {
    $item = "$key is required and cannot be null";
}
$rows = [
    'name'=> '',
    'tel' => '',
    'field' => 'someVal'
];


$errors = array_filter($rows,function($val) {
    return empty($val);
});
array_walk($errors,"fill_error");
```

It will both pull out your blanks, and fill your messages. Output:

> Array ( [name] => name is required and cannot be null [tel] => tel is
>   required and cannot be null )

Comment: i think this will work but am finding it tricky to assign the values to the associative array.

Comment: Remember to make the $item in the function a reference (pass byref) (fill_error(&$item,$key) ) so that it updates when you assign it (the purpose of array_walk($errors,"fill_error") is to assign those values for that.